# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with my code, otherwise I would not be here. I am running my code in functions and it is getting as far as the error yet when I re-read through my code, there looks to be 0 errors. How can I fix this? The code is all correctly indented on my program. My code is:

```
import os 
os.system('clear')
import random
import time
import math

def main_menu():
    menu = input("Please select the number of your choice: 1)Encrypt, 2)Decrypt, 3)Exit or 4)Extended encrypt \n") 
    if(menu == '1' or menu == 'Encrypt' or menu == 'encrypt' or menu == 'ENCRYPT'):
        return 1
    elif(menu == '2' or menu == 'Decrypt' or menu == 'decrypt' or menu == 'DECRYPT'):
        return 2
    elif(menu == '3' or menu == 'Exit' or menu =='exit' or menu == 'EXIT'):
        return 3
    elif(menu == '4' or menu =='Extended Encrypt' or menu == 'extended encrypt' or menu == 'EXTENDED ENCRYPT' or menu == 'Extended' or menu == 'extended' or menu == 'EXTENDED'):
        return 4
    else:
        return 5   

def menu_encrypt():
    print("Welcome to code encryption \n")
    usertext = file_read()
    offsetcode = offset_generator()    
    offsetcalc = offset_calc(offsetcode)
    plrencrypt = encrypt_str(usertext, offsetcalc)
    print(plrencrypt, "\n")
    write_file(plrencrypt)
    os.system('clear')

def offset_generator():
    c = 0
    offset = "" 
    while c < 8:
        num = random.randint(33,126)
        num = chr(num)
        offset = offset + num
        c = c + 1
    print("This is your code for decryption \n")
    print(offset, "\n")
    print("Please remember this code as it is important for decryption \n")
    return offset  

def file_read():
    while True:
        try:
            userfile = input("Please select the file you wish to use without the extension:   ")
            print("")
            f = open(userfile + ".txt")
            userprint = f.read()
            return userprint
            break
        except IOError:
            print("ERROR! The choice you have selected is invalid \n")

def offset_calc(offsetcode):
    osgen = 0
    for b in offsetcode:
        b = ord(b)
        osgen = osgen + b
    osgen = math.floor(osgen/8)-32
    return osgen

def encrypt_str(usertext, offsetcalc):
    userencrypt = ""
    for z in usertext:
        z = ord(z)
        if z == 32:
            z = chr(z)
            userencrypt = userencrypt + z
        else:    
            z = z + offsetcalc
            if z > 126:
                z = z - 94
            z = chr(z)
            userencrypt = userencrypt + z
    return userencrypt

def write_file(plrencrypt):
    newname = input('Please choose the name of your file:   ')
    fiile = newname + (".txt")
    newfile = open(fiile, "w")
    newfile.write(plrencrypt)
    newfile.close()


def input_offset(userarray):
    usergen = 0
    for a in userarray:
        a = ord(a)
        usergen = usergen + a
    usergen = math.floor(usergen / 8) -32
    return usergen


def menu_decrypt():
    print("Welcome to code decryption \n")
    userprint = file_read()
    userarray = ""
    while len(userarray) < 8:
        charcode = input("Please enter each character of the 8 character code you were given during encryption:   ")
        userarray = userarray + charcode
    usergen = input_offset(userarray)
    userdecrypt = decrypt_str(userprint, usergen)
    print(userdecrypt)
    time.sleep(5)
    os.system('clear')



def decrypt_str(userprint, usergen):
    userdecrypt = ("")
    for y in userprint:
        y = ord(y)
        if y == 32:
            y = chr(y)
            userdecrypt = userdecrypt + y
        else:
            y = y - usergen
            if y < 33:
                y = y + 94
            y = chr(y)
            userdecrypt = userdecrypt + y
    return userdecrypt


def menu_extended():
    print("Welcome to code encryption \n")
    usertext = file_read()
    offsetcode = offset_generator()    
    offsetcalc = offset_calc(offsetcode)
    plrencrypt = extended_str(usertext, offsetcalc)
    print(plrencrypt, "\n")
    write_file(plrencrypt)
    os.system('clear')


def extended_str(usertext, offsetcalc):
    countering = 0
    userencrypt = ""
    for b in usertext:
        b = ord(b)
        if b == 32:
            b = chr(b)
            usertext = usertext - b
        else:    
            while countering < 5:
                b = b + offsetcalc
                if b > 126:
                    b = b - 94
                b = chr(b)
                userencrypt = userencrypt + b
                countering = countering + 1
                if countering == 5:
                    countering = 0
                    userencrypt = userencrypt + ' '
    return userencrypt   


while True:   

    total = 0
    menupoints = main_menu()
    total = total + menupoints


    if menupoints == 1:
        menu_encrypt()
    elif menupoints == 2:
        menu_decrypt()
    elif menupoints == 3:
        print("")
        print("Thank you for using our services", "\n")
        os.system('clear')
        break
    elif menupoints == 4:
        menu_extended()
    elif menupoints == 5:
        print("ERROR! The choice you have selected is invalid", "\n")
        main_menu()
    else:
        ()
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, where exactly are you getting the error. Also fix the indentation under your `while`

Comment: Your code isn't indented properly. You should pay attention to these details when posting. It really speeds things up for the people who try to answer

Comment: You should also read and follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). For example, it's `if foo:` and not `if(foo):` and instead of including both upper and lowercase options you could convert it to lowercase/uppercase and only check that one.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Sometimes making a MCVE leads you to finding the problem yourself.

Comment: FWIW, you can shorten some of your comparisons. E.g. `menu == 'Encrypt' or menu == 'encrypt' or menu == 'ENCRYPT'` can be shortened to `menu.lower() == 'encrypt'`. Folding before testing will often shorten your test expressions.

Comment: "its getting as far as the error" is like saying your plane made it as far as the crash site. You should tell the first responders where the crash site is.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, it seemed to work on my end when I copied-and-pasted the code into my Python 3 interpreter. I encrypted and decrypted a few files just fine using numbers to mark my selection.

My only diagnosis is that it's possible you also have a copy of Python 2 in your machine, and your program may be executing under Python 2 accidentally. Your entire program is valid Python 2 code, but the behavior of input() is different and quirky in Python 2. If that's the case, add  a #! py -3 to the top of your code, like this:

```
#! py -3
import os
```

etc.

As others have echoed, it would be A+ if you could be a bit more specific when asking questions. I just assumed by 'error' you meant the error text displayed when the user inputs an invalid selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input('Enter a nine digit integer: '))
if len(number) == 9:
    temp = int(number)
    totalSum = 0
    i = 8;
    while i>=0:
        digit = temp//(10**i)
        multiplied = digit * (i+2)
        print(str(digit) + ' * ' + str(i+2) + ' = ' + str(multiplied))
        totalSum += multiplied
        temp -= digit*(10**i)
        i -= 1
        print(totalSum)

        if totalSum % 11 == 1:
            isbn = number + 10
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 2:
            isbn = number + 9
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 3:
            isbn = number + 8
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 4:
            isbn = number + 7
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 5:
            isbn = number + 6
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 6:
            isbn = number + 5
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 7:
            isbn = number + 4
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 8:
            isbn = number + 3
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 9:
            pisbn = number + 2
            print(isbn)
        elif totalSum % 11 == 10:
            isbn = number + 1
            print(isbn)



else:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: What I meant is that I it says: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly. I think the problem happens when adding number to a digit, but don't know what